# ValueError in Django when running the "python manage.py migrate" command

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations, django-users

I needed to add more fields to Django's **User** model, so I created a custom model class (named **Accounts** in an app named **accounts**) that extends Django's **AbstractUser** class.

After that, I updated my **settings.py** file, defining the **AUTH_USER_MODEL property**:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Accounts'
```

I then created a migration file for the custom model using the `python manage.py makemigrations` command.

After that, I ran the `python manage.py migrate` command and I got this error message:

```
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'accounts.accounts', but app 'accounts' isn't installed.
```

What's the cause of the error and how can I fix it?

UPDATE:
Now, if i run the `python manage.py makemigrations` command, I get this error message:

```
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'accounts.accounts', but app 'accounts' doesn't provide model 'accounts'.
```

Comment: Do you have the `accounts` package in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @koniiiik, this is what I have in `INSTALLED_APPS`: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'inyavic.apps.InyavicConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid we'll have to see the full traceback to be able to help further. Just add it to your question (you might also list the `INSTALLED_APPS` there to make it easier to read).

Answer (score 14):

You just delete your previous 0001_initial.py in the migrations folder and try doing the makemigration and migrate again

Comment: The solution is to do the migrations yourself.  Simply deleting the migration and recreating migrations will leave the cruft that was the original user model in your db - i.e., bad for a production system.  So figure out what's acceptable.  If you don't need any of your current data, then totally nuke your db and migrations and rebuild from scratch.  If you're still at migration 0001, then this might be okay.  But if you need to preserve data, then figure out how to do it manually.  We can't know from this post if, say, there are any `User` rows that need preserved in `Accounts`.

Comment: tldr: this seems to be rooted in that changing the core user model breaks the migration system.  So you need to understand what the migration would have ideally done for you and do it manually.

Comment: To add to this, be aware that if you're making model changes in different apps, and deleting migrations to try and makemigrations again, there might've been migration files created in both apps.  I got the error because I deleted 0001_initial.py in app1/migrations but didn't delete 0121_somemigrations.py from app2/migrations.  Then I ran "python manage.py makemigrations" and got this error.  After I deleted 0121_somemigrations.py, everything worked again.

Answer (score 2):

I have the similar problem. It is the admin app has the cache and migrations history.  I solve it by deleting all the cache and migrations history record(*pycache* file, and 0001.intial etc., keep *init*.py only) in
YouProject\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\migrations

Answer (score 2):

I too had a similar problem when I changed the name of one of my apps, I had to delete migrations files at two locations, all migrations for the specific app migration folder, then migrations at "Your-project-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/migrations".

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add `accounts` to your INSTALLED_APPS. From the comment, I can see `accounts.apps.AccountsConfig` in your list of apps. Instead of it, just add `accounts` to your INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 1):

It's just because you have already an instance of default user model I think. Start a new project and migrate your models again and it should work.

Comment: How can I start a new project when I get this issue somewhere middle of my project where everything is working fine since 2 years!!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
look under your class in `models.py`, change the `app_label` to the name of your application, I put the name of the class, and then the error came. doing this I think it fixes the errors.

```
class Meta:
        app_label = 'put_app_name'
```

Sorry for some grammar error, I'm using google translator.